# How can I loop and generate keys for maps with XSLT 3.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I tried to construct a new map. In my source xml I've got many products (product data and IDs). How can I generate so many keys like products?

The goal is a transformation from XML to XML with XSLT. The idea was to create a map and in a next step call the keys for adressing the specifics product datas I need. So I need to know if this is possible with using maps or is there another solution?

Example for the source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <id>102</id>
        <product>Lenovo 1234</product>
        <productfamily>laptop</productfamily>
    </row>
    <row>
    .....
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="val" as="map(xs:integer, xs:integer)">
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:for-each select="//id"> 
      <xsl:map-entry key="" select="."/>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:variable>    

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="map:get($val , 102)"/>    
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which values do you want to store in the map? You have declared a map from integer to integer. I suppose the `id` will be the key but I am not sure which integer value you want to store in the map as the value.

Comment: "The goal is a transformation from XML to XML with XSLT.": show us the target XML you want for your input sample, perhaps it becomes clearer. In general XSLT can transform XML to XML since XSLT 1 and doesn't need to use any maps for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a map based on a simple functional relationship in the data you can do

```
<xsl:variable name="index" as="map(*)">
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:for-each select="//x">
      <xsl:map-entry key=".//@id" select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:variable>
```

or if you prefer

```
<xsl:variable name="index" as="map(*)"
  select="map:merge(//x ! map:entry(.//@id, .))"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for!